# Simple CRUD application with n layered architecture

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I had a technical test with a simple CRUD application where I used n layered architecture as explained on the [Patterns In Action](http://www.dofactory.com/products/pro-net-design-pattern-framework) book that I bought.

However after delivering one of their feedbacks was the following.

> DbContext lifetime is completely wrong. (literally)

I will copy the relevant files on this question, because I want to learn what I did wrong and if that product I bought has just problems conceptually.

So, in my `DataAccess` class library I have this:

```
namespace DataObjects
{   
    // abstract factory interface. Creates data access objects.
    // ** GoF Design Pattern: Factory.
    public interface IDaoFactory
    {
        //Product Dao interface that must be implemented by each provider
        IProductDao ProductDao { get; }
        //Color Dao interface that must be implemented by each provider
        IColorDao ColorDao { get; }
        //Size Dao interface that must be implemented by each provider
        ISizeDao SizeDao { get; }
        //Category Dao interface that must be implemented by each provider
        ICategoryDao CategoryDao { get; }
        //File Dao interface that must be implemented by each provider
        IFileDao FileDao { get; }
        //File Error Dao that must be implemented by each interface
        IFileErrorDao FileErrorDao { get; }
    }
}
```

Then I have also this Interface

```
using BusinessObjects;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DataObjects
{
    public interface ICategoryDao
    {
        //Gets a list of categories
        List<Category> GetCategories();
        //Inserts one category 
        void InsertCategory(Category category);
        //To verify if category exists
        bool CategoryExists(string category);
        //Get Category by name
        Category GetCategoryByName(string category);
    }
}
```

And now, in the EntityFramework namespace I have the following implementations

```
namespace DataObjects.EntityFramework
{
    // Data access object factory
    // ** Factory Pattern
    public class DaoFactory : IDaoFactory
    {
        public IProductDao ProductDao => new ProductDao();
        public IColorDao ColorDao => new ColorDao();
        public ISizeDao SizeDao => new SizeDao();
        public ICategoryDao CategoryDao => new CategoryDao();
        public IFileDao FileDao => new FileDao();
        public IFileErrorDao FileErrorDao => new FileErrorDao();
    }

}
```

`DaoCategory` implementation

```
using AutoMapper;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using BusinessObjects;

namespace DataObjects.EntityFramework
{
    // Data access object for Product
    // ** DAO Pattern

    public class CategoryDao : ICategoryDao
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Inserts category into database
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="category"></param>
        public void InsertCategory(Category category)
        {
            using (var context = new ExamContext())
            {
                Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Category, CategoryEntity>());
                var entity = Mapper.Map<Category, CategoryEntity>(category);
                context.CategoryEntities.Add(entity);
                context.SaveChanges();
                // update business object with new id
                category.Id = entity.Id;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets all categories from database
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Returns a list of Category</returns>
        public List<Category> GetCategories()
        {
            using (var context = new ExamContext())
            {
                Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<CategoryEntity, Category>());
                var categories = context.CategoryEntities.ToList();
                return Mapper.Map<List<CategoryEntity>, List<Category>>(categories);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Verifies if one category name exists
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="category">Category name</param>
        /// <returns>Returns true if exists</returns>
        public bool CategoryExists(string category)
        {
            using (var context = new ExamContext())
            {
                return context.CategoryEntities.Any(x => x.CategoryName == category);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets color by name
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="categoryName">color name</param>
        /// <returns>Category</returns>
        public Category GetCategoryByName(string categoryName)
        {
            using (var context = new ExamContext())
            {
                Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<CategoryEntity, Category>());
                var category = context.CategoryEntities.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CategoryName == categoryName);
                return Mapper.Map<CategoryEntity, Category>(category);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Improve your question title to sum up shortly what this code is siupposed to do please.

Comment: Not much of an improvement so far, sorry.

Comment: What about telling us about that Factory pattern implementation? Also isn't that product you bought meant to generate that stuff for you?

Comment: Is this an interview question?

Comment: a technical test question.

Comment: the product I bought its guidance, there is no code generator there whatsoever

Comment: @Luis You probably failed in how to use that framework properly but implemented your own stuff. _"there is no code generator there whatsoever"_ The link says otherwise.

Comment: the description of the product is wrong, IT HAS a geneator called Spark, but thats only 25% of the product, it also has guidance on GoF Patterns and Patters in Action book.

Comment: @Luis _"the description of the product is wrong"_ May be ou simply didn't grasp how to use it correctly. I honestly can't tell.

Comment: Does this code work and only the architecture is wrong or is something else wrong with it?

Comment: I think the question is very clear,  they are telling me that the LIFECYCLE of DbContext is completely wrong, based on your own experience with EntityFramework do you agree with them? and why, how can I improve it based on the code you see above?, Forget the Product I bought. :)

Comment: @Luis Well, the lifetime of a _Factory_ should last for the overall lifetime of the application (that's why factories are often implemented as _Singleton_s). The lifetime of the handed out instances should be decoupled from the _Factory_ and owner semantics an lifetime management goes to the client.

Comment: Yes it does compile and it works.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  the question is about lifetime of DbContext only, not about the factories, they said DbContext lifetime is completely wrong but give no further details of why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Entity Framework's `DbContext` is really a unit of work. By newing them up inside each method you lose the ability to do several interesting things in the same transaction/unit of work in an easy way. You should be able to have multiple repositories (Dao in your parlance) using the same context/unit of work.

Your code is also incredibly coupled to EF and you're violating the dependency inversion principle.

This is the best write up of DbContext lifetime that I've ever read: [Managing DbContext the right way with Entity Framework 6: an in-depth guide](http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6). Although you're not actually using any of the 3 main patterns discussed.

If that `Mapper` is Automapper, that's also the wrong place to be configuring it and is a conflation of concerns.

Comment: thank you, can you please ellaborate more about the Automapper? where it should be? I just based my code on patterns in action sample code from www.dofactory.com product I bought

Comment: can you please also ellaborate more about the vioation of DI, and how to fix it, or a good sample about it

Comment: @LuisValencia-MVP Automapper here: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration. Main point is to have the configuration happen once. Not every time you use it. Note also that the instance API is generally preferred over the static API too.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason for why the lifetime of the `DbContext` should be completely wrong. It's too general and probably just meant to not let you pass the question.

The only things that I'm not so fond of are

- the mapping between the EF entities and and DTOs - why would you want to do this? Don't you have more interesting code to write? ;-)
- the `Dao` suffix polution everywhere.
- I've never seen any real world application where something as trivial as CRUD only would work. You always have joins and other sophisticated inserts so it's nice only in theory. You also almost never need CRUD interfaces for every entity type becasue some of them cannot exist without some other ones and need to be inserted/deleted together.